# what does "single" in "the single fastest way" mean?

Tags: meaning

The course info says:

> These micro-courses are the single fastest way to gain the skills
>   you'll need to do independent data science projects.

the fastest way is easy to understand, which means you will spend least time to master(or finish) something.

usually, the fastest implies only one or top one, why bother to add another "single"?

what does "the single fastest way" mean?

Comment: @shi95 I've edited your question to remove the name and link to the commercial product, as these are quite superfluous to the question itself. You can roll back the edit if you wish, but that might give rise to the suspicion that the question is spam. NB I haven't bothered with your lack of capitalisation - I suggest you [edit] to fix that yourself, as lazy orthography on a site for *"serious English language enthusiasts"* risks downvotes :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Single" refers to the fact that this way is the only one that fast. To put it in perspective, a car, car A, can be the fastest, but it can also not be alone on that. Another car, car B, can be equally fast. Car A is still the fastest car, so is car B, but neither are the "single most fastest" car.

So, "single" implies it is without equal in its speed.